# Codeception WebDriver installation

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, codeception

I'm using this documentation for testing codeception in a firefox browser
http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver

I have everything set up, as I previously played around a bit with codeception with PhpBrowser.
But I have an issue running codeception with the selenium WebDriver, it's kind of a newbie question but here I go:

After I make the command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.xx.xxx.jar
```

My console gets kinda stuck saying

```
INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@1037d830
```

What do I have to do to start codeception after that?
When I was using only PhpBrowser I started it with:

```
php codecept.phar run
```

Do I have to specify WebDriver's location somewhere or something? I can't find a lot of info about this, just tutorials for eclipse and such where they drag and drop and specify by code, and the documentation it's not very conforting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work in the background with

```
nohup java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.xx.xxx.jar &
```

after that I just executed it normally with

```
php codecept.phar run
```